# Bunder is installing with rubygems dependency not version in gem directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, bundler

I'm using **rbenv** to manage my Rubies. Heroku seems to only (or at least prefer) Bundler `v1.15.2` according to their [Ruby Support docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/categories/working-with-bundler).

So I:

`$ bundle exec gem install bundler -v 1.15.2`

and that's the only version of Bundler in Ruby 2.4.4's gem directory.

However when I `bundle install` or `bundle update` the `Gemfile.lock` says:

```
BUNDLED WITH
   1.16.2
```

And that gives me warnings in deployment (Heroku) and even locally every time I `bundle update <some_gem>`.

I did update **rubygems recently**:

```
$ gem -v
2.6.14.1
$ gem update --system
Updating rubygems-update
Fetching: rubygems-update-2.7.7.gem (100%)
Successfully installed rubygems-update-2.7.7
Installing RubyGems 2.7.7
Bundler 1.16.2 installed
RubyGems 2.7.7 installed
Regenerating binstubs
```

Which explains why `bundler 1.16.2` is on my system but how can I force it to source the version in Ruby's directory and put an end to all these warnings:

> Warning: the running version of Bundler (1.15.2) is older than the
>   version that created the lockfile (1.16.2). We suggest you upgrade to
>   the latest version of Bundler by running `gem install bundler`.

**Edit:** `gem env` as per request

```
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.7.7
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.4.4 (2018-03-28 patchlevel 296) [x86_64-darwin18]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/meltemi/.rbenv/versions/2.4.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0
  - USER INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/meltemi/.gem/ruby/2.4.0
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /Users/meltemi/.rbenv/versions/2.4.4/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /Users/meltemi/.rbenv/versions/2.4.4/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /Users/meltemi/.gem/specs
  - SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: /Users/meltemi/.rbenv/versions/2.4.4/etc
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-darwin-18
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /Users/meltemi/.rbenv/versions/2.4.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0
     - /Users/meltemi/.gem/ruby/2.4.0
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
     - "gem" => "--no-document"
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
  - SHELL PATH:
     - /Users/meltemi/.rbenv/versions/2.4.4/bin
     - /usr/local/Cellar/rbenv/1.1.1/libexec
     - /Users/meltemi/.rbenv/shims
     - /usr/local/heroku/bin
     - .git/safe/../../bin
     - /Users/meltemi/.bin
     - /usr/local/sbin
     - /usr/local/bin
     - /usr/bin
     - /bin
     - /usr/sbin
     - /sbin
     - /opt/X11/bin
```

Comment: so you get the described bad behavior only when you don't prepend `bundle exec` to your gem commands?  Would you mind posting output of `gem env` ?

Comment: also see https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-ruby/issues/802

Comment: @lacostenycoder - I get same "bad" behavior whether I prepend `bundle exec` or not.